# How to generate and propagate traceId for zipkin js

Tags: node.js, express, http, zipkin

I use Zipkin js to get insight into how a particular service is too slow. But I don't have a view of the whole architecture because the b3 headers are not propagated between apps. On each app, a new traceid and spanid are generated. So, I'd like to use a lib like sleuth enables to generate a traceid and spanid and propagates them through applications. But I don't find a library for that. To you, How to do that, please?

Thanks in advance.